# Make an array from a select with multiple rows

Tags: php, arrays, select, implode

I'm trying my best here to find a solution for my issue, but with no luck.
I have a SELECT in my PHP to retrieve some products information like their IDs.

```
mysql_query("SELECT id_item FROM mytable WHERE status = '0' AND cond1 = '1' AND cond2 = '1'");
```

Every time I run this SELECT, I get 5 rows as result. After that I need to run a DELETE to kill those 5 rows using their id_item in my WHERE condition. When I run, manually, something like:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id_item IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

It works! But my issue is that I don't know how to make an array in PHP to return (1,2,3,4,5) as this kind of array from my SELECT up there, because those 2 other conditions may vary and I have more "status = 0" in my db that can't be killed together. How am I suppose to do so? Please, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why not just `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE status = 0`?

Comment: Sorry dude, but I wasn't clear enough. The point is that my SELECT has more 2 conditions in WHERE clause. So, only when I have status = '0' in those 2 conditions I should be able to kill those 5 rows. You know what I mean? That's why I try to retrieve only their IDs to make a DELETE query.

Comment: OK, then just add those conditions to the DELETE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is more going on than what is shown, you should never have to select just to determine what to delete.  Just form the DELETE query WHERE condition as you would in the SELECT:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE status = '0' AND cond1 = '1' AND cond2 = '1'
```

But to answer how to get the IDs:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id_item FROM mytable WHERE status = '0' AND cond1 = '1' AND cond2 = '1'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $ids[] = $row['id_item'];
}
$ids = implode(',', $ids);
```

**Move to PDO or MySQLi now.**

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! I've been learning even more with you all here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shouldn't be using `mysql_query` anymore as the function is deprecated - see [php.net](http://php.net/mysql_query)

If this is a legacy application and you MUST use `mysql_query` you'll need to loop through the resource that's returned by `mysql_query`, which should look something like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id_item FROM mytable WHERE status = '0' AND cond1 = '1' AND cond2 = '1'");

$idArray = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $idArray[] = $row['id_item'];
}

if(count($idArray) > 0) {
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id_item IN (" . implode(',' $idArray) . ")");
}
```

Comment: Nice and clean code. Though @user3854140 should really look in to PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, probably you don't even need a select. But you can do a select, grouping all ids together, and then put it in the delete `IN`.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id_item) AS ids FROM mytable WHERE status = '0' AND cond1 = '1' AND cond2 = '1'");

$ids = mysql_result( $result , 0, 'ids') ; // 1,2,3,4,5

if ($ids != ""){    
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id_item IN (" . $ids . ")");
}
```

[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)